# Использование Math Kernel Library в Visual С++

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Если есть знатоки, отзовитесь! Хотелось бы узнать, как использовать эту библиотеку в Visual Studio 2010, конкретно для перемножения матрицы на вектор.

Comment: Ради Бога, извините за оффтоп, но какие проблемы с этим действием? Напишите сами и пользуйтесь. Или я чего-то не понимаю? И в boost'е имеется...

Comment: Вы имеете в виду интеловскую библиотеку?

Comment: Нет, умножение матрицы на вектор.

Comment: @BuilderC, вообще-то это вопрос к @rejie

Comment: ну конечно, именно интелл! С оптимизацией кода под свой процессор!

Comment: Intel C++ Compiler встраивается в VS при установке.

Comment: @mikillskegg а не могли бы вы привести пример кода с использованием библиотеки интел для перемножения матриц!?